# What is the meaning of `if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-"]`?

Tags: bash

I was looking through the /etc/profile file and I noticed a strange if statement. Can someone let me know what this means?

I'm referring to the second if statement `if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-"]` .

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641334/13982210 "KamilCuks's answer") answers the question. but i am curious to know what system/distro you are using

Comment: Hi, I'm using centos 8 on virtual box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$-` outputs the list of options the shell is running with. `i` in the output of `$-` means that the shell is interactive.

`${var#expr}` removes from the value of `var` the part from the left that matches the `expr`. `expr` is a glob. In the case `expr` is not matched, the original string is just outputted.

So `${-#*i}` gets the value of `$-` and removes the part from the left that matches `*i`.

For example: `$-` is `himBHs`. The part that matches `*i` from the left is `hi`. So `hi` from the left will be removed. So `${-#*i}` will be `mBHs`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

> Can someone let me know what this means?

I believe it's an odd way of checking if the session is interactive.

I would very much prefer and recommend `case "$-" in *i*)` for readability and portability. Also https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html .

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack comparison that seems intended to work with shells not having the `==` operator and the pattern matching feature. It relies on checking if `$-` remains the same after `i` and everything that comes before it are attempted to be stripped from the beginning of its value. Unfortunately it might still not work as intended because even the `!=` operator is not common. The `!` operator along with `=` should be used instead.

Comment: `!=` is also part of POSIX.

Comment: I considered the possibility that's why I didn't specifically mentioned POSIX.